# The mean waiting time of the pattern from coin tossing

Tags: probability

Toss a coin at time-points t = 1, 2, . . .. Denote the outcome of each toss
head-facing-up and tail-facing-up by a 0 and a 1, respectively. Let $\Lambda=(0\ 0\ 1)$ and $N$ be the waiting time for $\Lambda$. Find the mean waiting time $E[N]$ with the probability of each toss of the head-facing-up is $\frac{1}{3}$.
The following is my thinking:
Conditioning on the outcome of the first coin toss and second coin toss, let $N=
    \begin{cases}
      2+N^\prime& if X_{t=1}=0 \ \&\ X_{t=2}=1\\
      2+N^* & if X_{t=1}=1 \ \&\ X_{t=2}=0\\
      2+N^{**} & if X_{t=1}=1 \ \&\ X_{t=2}=1\\
      2+N^{***} & if X_{t=1}=0 \ \&\ X_{t=2}=0\\
    \end{cases}     $
Here, $N^{**}$ and $N^\prime$ have the same distribution as $N$.
$N^*$ and $N^{***}$ have the same distribution.
$E[E[N \mid X_1,X_2]]=E[N]=(2+E[N^\prime]) \times \frac{2}{9}+(2+E[N^*])\times \frac{2}{9}+(2+E[N^{**}])\times \frac{4}{9}+(2+E[N^{***}])\times \frac{1}{9}$
However, I don't know how to describe the distribution of $N^*$ and $N^{***}$.  If I know their distribution, I can obtain the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the notation for clearer understanding, we want the waiting time for getting the first sequence of HHT
I shall use an approach proceeding step by step

Let $s$ be the starting state, $h_1$ the state where we have just tossed a head and $h_2$ the state where we have  tossed two consecutive heads, then

With one toss from start, we either toss a head with $Pr = \frac13,\;$ or remain where we are with $Pr =\frac23\;$ as shown in equation $[I]$

Framing equations step by step, we get
$\displaylines{s = \frac13(1+h_1) +\frac23(1+s)\;\;[I] \\h_1 = \frac13(1+h_2) +\frac23(1+s)\;\;[II]\\h_2 = \frac23\times 1 + \frac13(1+h_2)\;\;[III] }$

The last equation tells that from $HH,$ with $Pr=\frac23,\,$ we toss a tail and are done, or with $Pr=\frac13$, we remain poised at $HH$

Solve to get $s = 13.5$

---

**Additional Material**

Maybe the equations will be clearer if written in a  different form

$\displaylines {s = 1+ \frac13h_2 +\frac23h_1\;\;[I]\\h_1= 1+\frac13h_2 +\frac23 s\;\;[II]\\h_2= 1+\frac13h_2\;\;[III]}$

The first equation now  tells very clearly that from start, one step (or time unit) either leads to  the first H in the desired chain  with $Pr= \frac13$, or back to square one with $Pr = \frac23$
Similarly, the last equation means that with one step, either you go back to a HH situation with $Pr=\frac23$, or are done.

The technique is called *first step analysis*, which you can look up if you want further explanation or examples, also look at this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083871/something-maybe-related-to-stochastic-process/4084611#4084611) which addresses a somewhat more complex problem, and contrasts it with a stochastic matrix approach.

Comment: I still can't realize the meaning of $s$. What does the starting state mean?

Comment: The starting state is when you haven't yet tossed the coin, or when , say, you haven't achieved HHT and the chain has been broken, eg if you toss T, or HT, you are back to a state where you still require the first H of the HHT chain you want. Square $1$, so to say.

Comment: How do you generate the  equation above? Do you use markov chain? But the form doesn't seem like the markov chain I have seen before.

Comment: Yes, it is a Markov chain, I will add the equations in a different form, maybe that will help