# Expected value of times of pick balls without replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider there are 5 balls, I might pick 0,1,2,3 balls each time (each one has 0.25 probability). What is the expectation of times that I pick all 5 balls. (If the number left balls are smaller than the number I will pick this round, it will be considered as I pick all the left balls)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you attempted something by yourself? Consider how many ways there are of picking all balls and also consider the total number of ways to pick balls.

Comment: I have tried the markov process but I think the answer is not quite right. The code and the result is here. I simply use python to simulate this process.

Comment: `import numpy as np
n = 10 
i = 0
x = np.array([
    [1],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0]])
P = np.array([
    [0.25,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0.25,0.25,0,0,0,0],
    [0.25,0.25,0.25,0,0,0],
    [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0,0],
    [0,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0],
    [0,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1]
])  
P=P.T
print(P)
while i < n:
    P = np.dot(P,P)  # x=P*x
    i = i+1
    print('P(x='+str(i)+'): '+str(P[0,5]))`

Comment: P(x=1): 0.1875
P(x=2): 0.7421875
P(x=3): 0.9925689697265625
P(x=4): 0.9999988756608218
P(x=5): 0.9999999999999968
P(x=6): 1.0
P(x=7): 1.0
P(x=8): 1.0
P(x=9): 1.0
P(x=10): 1.0

Comment: @plusgrey: If you want to compare my method with matrix method, see my answer and comment box at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083871/something-maybe-related-to-stochastic-process/4084611#4084611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let cumulative total
of $\;0,1,2,3,4,5$ attained be denoted by $\;x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$

Tracing  movements step by step from one cumulative total to another, we count the # of steps (= time) needed to reach $5$

From a cumulative total of $0$, for instance, with $\frac14$ probability each, in one step you either remain at $0$ or jump to $1,2,3$
This is denoted by the first of the equations below.

$\displaylines{x_0=1+\frac14 x_0+ \frac14 x_1+\frac14 x_2+\frac14 x_3 \\x_1=1+ \frac14 x_1+ \frac14 x_2+ \frac14 x_3+ \frac14 x_4\\x_2=1+ \frac14 x_2+ \frac14 x_3+ \frac14 x_4\\x_3 = 1+ \frac14 x_3+ \frac14 
 x_4\\x_4= 1+ \frac14 x_4}$

Regarding $x_5$ missing from the equations, look at the last equation, for instance. From $x_4$, with one step either we remain at $x_4$ with Pr = $\frac14$, *or we are done*, so it is not necessary to include $x_5$ in the equations

We want to know the number of steps from start at $x_0$

Solving this system of linear equations, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x_0%29%3D1%2B%28x_0%29%2F4%2B%28x_1%29%2F4%2B%28x_2%29%2F4%2B%28x_3%29%2F4%2C+%28x_1%29%3D1%2B%28x_1%29%2F4%2B%28x_2%29%2F4%2B%28x_3%29%2F4%2B%28x_4%29%2F4%2C+%28x_2%29%3D1%2B%28x_2%29%2F4%2B%28x_3%29%2F4%2B%28x_4%29%2F4%2C%28x_3%29+%3D+1%2B%28x_3%29%2F4%2B%28x_4%29%2F4%2C%28x_4%29%3D1%2B%28x_4%29%2F4) gives

$x_0 = \frac{916}{243}, \approx 3.77$

Comment: I think the solution works very well, at least I do not see errors. Just as a reference to clarify your procedure: https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf

Comment: Only, as a notational thing, you used the same letter for the states and the expected times, which can hinder maybe the clarity of the solution (but +1 from my side!)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I am still wandering that is it possible to use Markov stochastic matrix to solve this question? How can I do that. Thansk again.

Comment: @plusgrey see the pdf which uses the notation of markov processes to derive the solution of true blue anil

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your inputs and kind words. I am not a mathematician, but I have tried to improve the answer. Hopefully it is clearer now, even using just one set of symbols.

Comment: @plusgrey consider accepting the answer if it satisfied for needs ;)