# Probability of seeing HTTH before THTH in coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, martingales, stopping-times

I'm doing a past paper question and trying to use Doob's Optional Stopping to find the probability that for independent identical $(X_n)$ uniform on $\{0,1\}$ we see the pattern $a = (1,0,0,1)$ before the pattern $b = (0,1,0,1)$, and so wonder whether this is correct, and/or an efficient method since applying Doob's twice doesn't necessarily seem like the quickest way.

We consider stopping times $\tau_w = \text{inf}\{n \in \mathbb N \mid (X_{n-3},\dots,X_n) = w\}$ for $w \in \{a,b\}$, and $\tau = \tau_a \wedge \tau_b$.

As usual we'll set up gamblers entering a casino, all bets double or nothing gambler $A^i$ entering at time $i$ starting with $1$ and betting on the first letter for $a$, then second, etc., gambler $B^i$ starting with $1$ and betting on consecutive letters for $b$.

Then let $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n A^i_n + B^i_n - 2n$ earnings of $A^i_n$ and $B^i_n$, and $N_n = \sum_{i=1}^n A^i_n + 2 \cdot B^i_n - 3n$ earnings for $A^i_n$ and $2 \cdot B^i_n$. Then it follows that these are martingales as a (infinite) sum of martingales starting at 0 ($A^i_n - 1$ for instance is such a martingale, and is $0$ for $n < i$) since the game is fair.

Then we have that $\tau$ has finite expectation since
$$
\mathbb P(\tau > 4n) \leq \mathbb P\bigg((X_{4m-3},\dots,X_m) \not = a \ \forall m \leq n\bigg) \leq (15/16)^n
$$
and so since both $M_n$ and $N_n$ have increments bounded by $32 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$, we apply Doob's twice:

At $\tau_a$, we have a gambler with 4 correct letters on $a$, one with 1 correct letter on $a$, and one with 2 correct letters on $b$.

At $\tau_b$, we have a gambler with 4 correct letters on $b$, one with 2 correct letters on $b$, and one with 1 correct letter on $a$.

So applying Doob's to both $M_n^\tau$ and $N_n^\tau$, writing $p = \mathbb P(\tau = \tau_a)$, and splitting the first expectation based on whether $\tau = \tau_a$ or $\tau = \tau_b$:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \mathbb E[M_0]= \mathbb E[M_\tau]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^\tau A^i_n + B^i_n\right] - 2* \cdot \mathbb E[\tau]\\
&= p \cdot (2^4 + 2^1 + 2^2) + q \cdot (2^1+2^4+2^2) - 2 \mathbb E[\tau]\\
&= 2 \cdot (11 - \mathbb E[\tau])
\end{align*}
$$
so that $\mathbb E[\tau] = 11$, and then doing the same again
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \mathbb E[N_0]= \mathbb E[N_\tau]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^\tau A^i_n + 2\cdot B^i_n\right] - 3* \cdot \mathbb E[\tau]\\
&= p \cdot (2^4 + 2^1 + 2\cdot 2^2) + q \cdot (2^1+2\cdot 2^4+2\cdot 2^2) - 3\cdot 11\\
&= 26p +42q - 33\\
&= 42-33-16p
\end{align*}
$$
so that $p = \dfrac{9}{16}$. The denominator of $16$ makes me think maybe there's a much quicker combinatorial/Markov chain way of getting to the same answer? Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is a way based on first step analysis, which essentially breaks down the possibilities resulting from the first step (first transition) in the Markov chain and proceeds step by step.

Calling the starting state before any toss as $s$, *probabilities* of moving to  the next possible state as $H=a, T= b, HT = c, HTT=d,TH=h, THT=k,$
with border probabilities $HTTH=1, THTH = 0$, we get

$\displaylines{s = (1/2)a+(1/2)b\\a = (1/2)c+(1/2)a\\b = (1/2)h+(1/2)b\\c=(1/2)d+(1/2)h\\d=(1/2)h+(1/2)*1\\h=(1/2)k +(1/2)a\\ k = (1/2)d +(1/2)*0}$

Solving, [I get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s+%3D+%281%2F2%29*a%2B%281%2F2%29*b%2C+a+%3D+%281%2F2%29*c%2B%281%2F2%29*a%2C+b+%3D+%281%2F2%29*h%2B%281%2F2%29*b%2C+c%3D%281%2F2%29*d%2B%281%2F2%29*h%2C+d%3D%281%2F2%29*h%2B%281%2F2%29*1%2C+h%3D%281%2F2%29*k+%2B%281%2F2%29*a%2C+k+%3D+%281%2F2%29*d+%2B%281%2F2%29*0) $s = \frac9{16}$

Comment: I'll check mine again shortly - it seems like both methods are valid so it's odd to see two different answers.

Comment: Ah yes, I accidentally solved for $q$ instead of $p$ in mine - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: I find it difficult to see the rationale behind your "backwards" calculations, unless you can justify it by a bayesian approach ?

Comment: @Jean Marie: Is your query addressed to me or to George ? Anyway, mine is a Markovian approach, viz only the present state is relevant for predicting the probability(s) of the next state(s).

Comment: It is addressed to you.  I know the Markov property ; I have built the "finite automata" and I understand the "how" of your equations, but my question is about the "why" : I don't understand why setting $1$ and $0$ resp. to the end states' probabilities makes $s$, proceeding  backwards, gives the desired probability. You mention a "first step analysis" : do you have a reference ?

Comment: @Jean Marie: You could have a look at the link. The technique can be used (with suitable modification) to give the mean absorption time apart from the probability of absorption. https://probabilitytopics.wordpress.com/2017/12/15/first-step-analysis-and-fundamental-matrix/

Comment: @Jean Marie: For number of steps to absorption, you could have a look at this answer: where you, too, have left a comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083871/something-maybe-related-to-stochastic-process/4084611#4084611

Comment: Thanks in particular for the second reference. I am a little ashamed : I had completely forgotten this previous "encounter".

Comment: @JeanMarie: Don't worry, there's a story of a renowned Chief Accountant . People noted that   he invariably first opened the top drawer of his table, looked intently and closed it before starting work. Curiosity was rife about this strange ritual.  Alas, one day he had a heart attack as he was about to open the drawer and had to be rushed to hospital. When a curious colleague opened the top drawer, all he found was a large sheet of paper on which was written, "Debits on left side, Credits on right side"  Memory is a fickle thing even to the best of us ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: @true blue anil Thanks. Funny joke !